# Dynamic page render reactjs and calling functions from the template

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have several components. The main component is the **PageTemplate.js**, which describes the menu, search bar and site header. And also a place in the center for the content of other pages(functional components react).
The idea is to use the template(**PageTemplate.js**) on all pages of the site, since there is only one. And generate a block with content from other components (pages, ex. **EditRecord.js, NewRecord.js** etc).

I use a react-router and when going to **/EditRecord**, for example, my content block rendered edit's page(**EditRecord.js**) there

Now I have done it something like this:

Page transitions work and the content block generates the page I need.

but i have a huge problem. For example there is a page with a table with data(MainPage.js). And the search and search function are located in the template(PageTemplate.js). How can I transfer the state from the template(PageTemplate.js) to the page(MainPage.js) to change the data table there by search value from template? And also, if I, for example, will be on the other page(example on /NewRecord) and call teh search function in PageTemplate, then how can I tell the react, that now it is necessary to draw the main page(/) MainPage with new data by searched results?

Many thanks to all in advance;)

**router code:**

```
import { Main} from './pages/MainPage/Main';
import { EditRecordPage } from './pages/EditRecordPage/EditRecordPage';
import { NewRecord } from './pages/NewRecordPage/NewRecord';

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Main,
  },
  {
    path: '/EditRecord/:id',
    exact: true,
    component: EditRecordPage,
  },
  {
    path: '/NewRecord/',
    exact: true,
    component: NewRecord,
  }
];
```

**Code one of pages (they are identical except for the name):**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { PageTemplate } from '../../components/PageTemplate';
import { MainPage } from './MainPage';

export const Main = (props) => {

  return (
    <PageTemplate title={'Main page'} {...props}><MainPage/></PageTemplate>
  )
}
```

**Here is a chunk in the render of PageTemplate.js  where the page(main, edit etc) is rendered:**

```
 <Content
     className="site-layout-background"
     style={{
             padding: 24,
             margin: 0,
              minHeight: 280,
             }
 >
    <div {...props}/>//here is the required page(main, edit, new etc)
 </Content>
```

Comment: basically what you want is to transfer data across various routes right?

Comment: @PrateekThapa Depending on the route, I want to change the content of the block <Content> in PageTemplate 
Separate component(exNewRecord.js) is loaded there. It works now.
For example, when I switch to /NewRecord, I get NewRecord.js content in the block.
The main problem. e.g. search and searchfunction are described in PageTemplate.js but displaying information in MainPage
How I can pass the search value from PageTemplate to MainPage?
If, for example, I am stay not on the main page, but for example NewRecord then how can I make the search results page(MainPage) render by clicking search?